# Regex only matching once, not for all

Tags: java, regex

I have a string I want to match, which has content inside curly brackets I want to parse with regex in Java.

The string looks like:

```
#{apgarscore} >= 0 && #{apgarscore} < 4 && #{apgarcomment} == ''
```

I try to use `#\{(.+)\}`

The result is that it for some reason matches

```
apgarscore} >= 0 && #{apgarscore} < 4 && #{apgarcomment
```

rather than three separate values.

I tested it with [here](https://regex101.com/) which yields the same result.

Can anyone please help me understand what I need to do differently?

Comment: Forget about lazy matching, it is not the best solution. Use a negated character class `[^{}]`: `#\{([^{}]+)\}`.

Comment: If you need to understand the difference between greedy `.+` vs. lazy `.*`, read [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `.+` is greedy. This means that it would try to match as many characters as possible. To make it non-greedy, add a question mark after that.

```
#\{(.+?)\}
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/nR6pO0/1)

Comment: Thanks, that did it.